# Can i convert windows controller to android controller in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a game for windows platform and keyboard controller "**A,S,W,D & Like SPACE for jump**

And i need to convert android platform so how i can make mobile input controller and remove keyboard controller

Comment: Take a look at unity's new input system

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the new Input system and or Try using onscreen UI to use as mobile input.
[Mobile Joystick input in Unity.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zd75Jq37R60)